# File Uploads in Django

Tags: html, django, forms

I'm looking for a method to upload files from a web page built using Django, but *without* using django forms i.e. `from django import forms`.

Why? Simply because I can't get my head around why we need such a thing. I'm pretty sure it would be possible to handle files uploaded via form just like we can handle other POST data submitted via a form.

As a side note, I'll appreciate if someone can tell me the logic behind using django forms at all.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES

If request contained file uploads, request.FILES will contain instances of UploadedFile class allowing you to read data you've received from client.

---

Generally you should use Django Forms because they make it simpler to maintain forms and views that rely on them. Sure, if your form is going to contain just one field, it may look like overkill at first, but don't worry, ultimately that two-liner is far smaller (and thus easier to maintain) that custom form validation and cleanup in view would ever be.

Biggest profit is separation of concerns: because your form is separate class, it can be reused by multiple views, it can also be easily extended using Python's inheritance, and it can be tested separately from view.

This works in opposite way too by keeping your views easier to comprehend because all form's creation and validation logic lies somewhere else.

Once you'll learn forms API, writing forms Django-way ultimately becomes faster and simpler than handling request.POST directly from view. Django forms handle incoming data for you and perform basic cleaning and validation as well as types coercion. Without them you would have to invest time into writing boilerplate for forms cleanup, validation and error handling yourself.

Django Forms also provide "hooks" for hooking extra code to your forms when validation and cleanup of data occurs, allowing you to do extra stuff when field receives value. There's even model.Form that allows you to generate form from your model, saving you even more time.

Thanks to Django Forms you can focus

While we are at it, you should also have a read at following:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST

Those are mustknow's in order to keep your forms safe from basic sorts of attacks.